# Problem with getting users from firebase realtime database on unity engine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get all the users from firebase realtime database on the unity engine (c#)
but for some reason the foreach will only return the first one 8 times and he won't go to another what I am doing wrong?

I checked with `ChildrenCount` and it does have 8 children (All of the users)

```cs
private IEnumerator InitPlayerList()
{
    var task = db.Child("Users").Child(gm.currentLobbyInfo.pinCode.ToString()).OrderByChild("score").GetValueAsync();

    yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => task.IsCompleted);

    if (task.Exception != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Something wrong");
        yield break;
    }
    else
    {
        DataSnapshot data = task.Result;
        foreach (Transform child in playersLeaderboardPerant)
        {
            Destroy(child.gameObject);
        }

        foreach (DataSnapshot childSnap in data.Children) // Won't move to the other users
        {
            Debug.Log(childSnap.Child("username").Value.ToString());
            PlayerLeaderBoard instance = Instantiate<PlayerLeaderBoard>(playerLeaderBoardPrefab, playersLeaderboardPerant);
            instance.SetupPlayerLeaderboardInstance(childSnap.Child("username").Value.ToString(), 0, "test");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

with the `childSnap.key` it does get all the keys of te different users

[image]

Comment: That seems unexpected. Can you `Debug.Log(childSnap.Key);` in the loop and then show the output you get in the question?

Comment: Thanks, I tried and I get the 8 users with the key it does work
I updated the question with the photo

Comment: That makes it even more unexpected that it'd show the same user name for all of them. Can you show the output of the `Debug.Log(childSnap.Child("username").Value.ToString());` too, and replace the picture of the DB that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/).

Comment: Thank you I found the problem ,
it was working fine but my code wasn't updating the name so all of them had the same name

Comment: Good to hear you found the problem @Omer4213. 